# How to read auth.logs in AWS ec2 instance logs?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

We were looking into this file, /var/logs/auth.logs and shows this:

[image]

**(Question 1:)** Is this a possible hack attempt?

Using this website https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/59.173.173.107 I can track the origin of the IP address.

I also run this command last and shows this:
[image]

**(Question 2:)** What is the difference of `last` and auth.logs?

**(Question 3:)** What is `CRON[17637]` and `sshd[17686]`? 
**(Question 4:)** What does this line mean, `Received disconnect from 59.173.173.107: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]`? 
**(Question 5:)** Is this normal? Does everyone always get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more related to linux/unix and CRON/SSHD daemons than to E2C itself. It is not a security question.

But to answer... 
CRON is a daemon - task scheduler - starting tasks on specific events (i.e. once a day). The record in log says the CRON started a session with root privileges to run some scheduled tasks and ended the session afterwards.

Yes, this is normal.

SSHD is console used to remotely connect to and manage the server. Somebody from China was trying to connect and get authenticated to the SSH console (unsuccessfully). <s>Normal shutdown means that remote client sent a TCP FIN packet so the TCP connection was correctly closed (server didn't need to wait for the timeout).</s>
Normal shutdown means the client has sent a request to shutdown the ssh connection with the message specifying the reason for shutdown. Thanks for playing is just a common message hardcoded in the ssh client. See also https://serverfault.com/a/563303 for details.

And yes, its normal that somebody is trying to connect to your server and log in. It is good practice to limit access to administrative interfaces to authorised IP addresses only using the firewall.

regarding last, type "man last" to get your answer.

And also next time try to do some research on your own before you will ask.
i.e.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-system-authentication-logs-on-ubuntu

Comment: I haven't setup anything in CRON. So its aws builtin?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is using it to perform some regular tasks.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I did some research but this server whole thing is so new to me. This is a start. thank you very much!

Comment: and by the way, why is there `Thank you for playing` in the message

Comment: sorry I was wrong. Thank you for playing is sent by client when it is closing the connection explicitly. See https://serverfault.com/a/563303

Comment: please do not answer clearly off-topic questions